# @Scheduled method not triggered in Keycloak custom SPI

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, keycloak, quarkus

I have a custom provider in Keycloak Quarkus distribution.
I created a task with **@Scheduled**, but it's never triggered.

For simplicity, this is the only class I have:

[image]

scheduler dependency is added:

[image]

I packaged it in a JAR and deployed into the "providers" folder.
After the startup, "post construct" is printed but the "scheduled" method is never called.
What am I missing?

[image]

I'm expecting the scheduled method to run every 10 seconds.

Comment: Hello, why do you put version for Scheduler ? Are you including different version than your quarkus version ?

Comment: Hi, now I included the full pom.xml. I don't have dependencyManagement, I just deploy this JAR in Keycloak as a custom provider. I'm doing it wrong?